# Extract all digital signatures of file in powershell

Tags: powershell, digital-signature

I'm searching for an answer but didn't find something helping. I would like to know how to extract all digital signatures certificates of a specific file. I tried to use the following command-

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'my\path\to\file' .SignerCertificate"
```

This command finds one certificate of the file even if it has more than one. How can I find all the certificates of file using PowerShell?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can You post an example of file having more than one certificate so that we can try to replicate the issue ?

Comment: TeamViewer.exe is one file, for example. It has two signatures, and I wish to extract the certificate information for both

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get-CertChain.ps1
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$Computername,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$FilePath 

)

$parameters = @{
    Computername = $Computername
    ScriptBlock = {
        param($Filepath)
        $cert = (Get-AuthenticodeSignature $FilePath).SignerCertificate
        $chain = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain;
        $chain.Build( $cert );
        $chain.ChainElements | ForEach-Object {$_.Certificate}
    }
    ArgumentList = $Filepath
}

Invoke-Command @parameters
```

.\Get-CertChain.ps1 -Computername . -FilePath C:\temp\myfile.txt